# I am trying to use sql by the help of jstl but getting exception

Tags: jstl

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaCs2.png)

[image]

HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

Type Exception Report

Message /sql.jsp (line: [17], column: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaCs2.png)) According to TLD, tag [sql:setDataSource] must be empty, but is not

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /sql.jsp (line: [17], column: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaCs2.png)) According to TLD, tag [sql:setDataSource] must be empty, but is not
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:42)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:292)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:98)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseBody(Parser.java:1652)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseOptionalBody(Parser.java:1016)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseCustomTag(Parser.java:1291)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1470)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:144)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:244)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:105)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:206)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:386)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:362)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:346)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:605)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:400)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)

Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.

Apache Tomcat/9.0.37

Comment: FYI: JSTL's `<sql:...>` (and `<x:...>`) tags are officially discouraged since 2001 because they only encourage bad practices. Do not use them. Use normal Java code instead (JDBC or JPA) and ensure that you're reading up to date and authoritative resources while learning new technologies and not 20+ year old resources and/or resources maintained by amateurs.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I am asking this question for my knowledge.

Comment: For starters, error messages are usually excellent [search keywords](https://google.com/search?q=According+to+TLD%2C+tag+%5Bsql%3AsetDataSource%5D+must+be+empty%2C+but+is+not).

Comment: BalusC : Thank you, it has been resolved, i use self closing tags  </>